# H264 ByteStream to Image Files

Tags: java, ffmpeg, h.264, javacv, android-mediacodec

first time here so be gentle.

I've been working for a few weeks on a given H.264 byte stream:

**General notes:**

1. The Byte Stream is not from a file, it is being fed live to me from an external source.
2. The Byte Stream is encoded with Android's Media Codec.
3. When writing the stream into a file with a .H264 extension, VLC is able to play it properly.

**What I'm trying to achieve? One of the following:**

1. Converting the frames of the H264 stream to a saveable picture file (png/jpeg etc')
2. Converting the H264 raw bytes into a MP4 stream that can be played as source by a browser.

I tried already using JavaCV (FFmpegFrameGrabber) without any success, my main problem is that i have no idea how to parse the byte stream or what each "packet" means

**So, I've attached a text file with some of the packets I'm getting from the stream**
[H264 Packets](https://drive.google.com/open?id=16Yztd36IAzXKwDhhijztlcT8WHBpzKYF)

Comment: Ffmpeg can do both of those things very easily.

Comment: Hi @Tzah Mazuz, did you get a solution to this problem? I am trying to ddo the same thing with raw h264 bytes from Android's MediaCodec. I have tried using Xuggler and JavaCV(FFMpegFrameGrabber) all to no avail. FFMpegFrameGrabber basically hangs on the start method.

Answer (score 1):

> Converting the frames of the H264 stream to a saveable picture file (png/jpeg etc')

Assuming you are using the `ffmpeg` cli tool.

Single image:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -i input.h264 -frames:v 1 output.png
```

Single image at 01:23:45 timestamp:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 24 -i input.h264 -ss 01:23:45 -frames:v 1 output.png
```

All images. Will be named `output_0001.png`, `output_0002.png`, `output_0003.png`, etc. No need to set `-framerate` or `-frames:v` in this case.

```
ffmpeg -i input.h264 output_%04d.png
```

See [FFmpeg image muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-2) for more info.

> Converting the H264 raw bytes into a MP4 stream that can be played as source by a browser.

```
ffmpeg -framerate 24000/1001 -i input.h264 -c copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.
Maybe i wasn't clear, I'm getting the stream from an external source (lets say a socket connected to a server) and i cant nor want to put it inside a h264 file.
Can i convert each frame and frame of the LIVE stream to a playable mp4 stream? or to pictures?

Comment: @TzahMazuz Yes. See available input [protocols](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html). It is unclear what protocols you want to use so I can't provide more details.

Comment: We can also run that from Java easily this way: http://bytedeco.org/javacpp-presets/ffmpeg/apidocs/org/bytedeco/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.html