# H264 fragments to Image Files

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, h.264, amazon-kinesis-video-streams

first time here so be gentle.

I followed following:

[H264 ByteStream to Image Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60139561/h264-bytestream-to-image-files)

with this, I am able to correctly generate an image for the very first fragments.

However, when I am trying for the subsequent fragments (.h264), I am getting following error:

[h264 @ 0x5a8f640] Format h264 detected only with low score of 1, misdetection possible!
[h264 @ 0x5a8f640] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264, none): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, h264, from 'frame-0003.h264':
Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #0:0: Video: h264, none, 24 tbr, 1200k tbn, 48 tbc
Output #0, image2, to 'output.png':
Output file #0 does not contain any stream

My fragments are named in following manner:

frame-0001.h264, frame-0002.h264 ..... frame-1500.h264

Is there any way I can create images for all the 1500 fragments. Any guidance, help or code is very appreciated.

Comment: concat them all together and use that as input

Comment: Hi, I used concat and it created a file but only with the first fragment.

Comment: How did you concat?

Comment: This is the command that I used: Ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy outputnew.h264 | mylist.txt contains frames in following format: file ‘frame-1486.h264'
file ‘frame-1487.h264')

Comment: No, concat the files together using `cat` or similar.

Comment: That worked. Thanks alot Gyan!

Comment: Any idea how resolution of the resulting frames can be increased? Or should I post another question for it. Sorry for being naive.

Comment: The decoder will output native resolution. Add a scale filter to resize decoded frames.